# Orthogonal matrix proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove this?
Let $\mathrm X \in O(2)$ be a order two orthogonal matrix, than $\mathrm X \in R[\theta] \vee X \in T[\theta]$ i.e. $\mathrm X$ is necessarily a rotation matrix of $\mathrm V_2$ or a reflection matrix of $\mathrm V_2$
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
x&y\\z&t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is an orthogonal matrix iff the columns are orthogonal unit vectors.

This means that $x^2+z^2=1$ and $y^2+t^2=1$ so there is a real number $\theta$ such that $x=\cos \theta$ and $z=\sin \theta$ and, since the second column have be orthogonal to the first, we must have: $y=-z$ and $ t=x$, or $y=z$ and $t=-x$. The first case  gives:
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta &-\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta&\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the second case gives:

$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta &\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta&-\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Locking at how these matrices act on the vector of the standard basis $i=[1,0]^T$ and $j=[0,1]^T$ we see that the first represents a rotation and the second a reflection.